# Building Hadoop on Windows 8.1. MojoException

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, build, sdk

I am trying to build Hadoop 2.7.3 on windows 8.1. There are numerous similar problems on stackoverflow but I could not solve the issue with the build I am trying. Following is the full stack trace after running the command with -e switch.

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven plugin:1.3.1:exec (compile-ms-winutils) on project hadoop-common: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.1:exec (compile-ms-wi nutils) on project hadoop-common: Command execution failed. at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356) Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command execution failed. at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:303)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:402)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:164)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:750)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:292)
    ... 22 more
```

I am using SDK 8.1, maven 3.3.9, java 1.8, protoc 2.5.0, CMake 3.7, Git 2.10.2 and .net framework 4.5.1 with all the path variables properly set. I resolved some other issues during the process taking help form different posts here but badly stuck with this error message. Any help please?